# How to sanitized HTML in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sanitize

I am trying to display HTML content on React front side.

### Here is my input

```html
<p>Hello/<p>

Aadafsf

<h1>H1 in hello</h1>
```

I write this from CKEditor from Admin side

### This is the React result in front size

```html
&lt;p&gt;Hello/&lt;p&gt;

Aadafsf

&lt;h1&gt;H1 in hello&lt;/h1&gt;
```

### This is the result I would like

```html
<p>Hello/<p>

Aadafsf

<h1>H1 in hello</h1>
```

### Here is what I tried so far

#### 1. Using `dompurify`

```js
import {Parser} from "html-to-react";
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";

{Parser().parse(DOMPurify.sanitize(HTMLCONTENT))}
```

[image: Screenshot of the output]

I tried this but I'm not getting the expected output.

#### 2. Using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

I have the below HTML content:

```html
<h2>This is Heading</h2><p>&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</p><p>This is para.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>This is Bold</strong></p><p>&nbsp;</p><ol><li><strong>dwsfdf</strong></li><li><strong>fdsfdf</strong></li></ol><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><figure class="media"><oembed url="https://youtu.be/rokGy0huYEA"></oembed></figure>
```

I used it like:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: HTMLCONTENT}} />;
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your mistake is not on the serialization, it is because there is a typo in your HTML.

The `<p>` tag is "closed" by a `/<p>` tag and not by a `</p>` !

So you need to update your HTML:

```
-  <p>Hello/<p>
+  <p>Hello</p>

Aadafsf

<h1>H1 in hello</h1>
```

Also, in order to display raw HTML in your component. React offer a function for that [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

But, take real care as this can open your site to attacks known as [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: it seems `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`  is not working. I updated

Comment: @MeetPatel I actually found your issue and updated my answer. There is a typo in your `/<p>` closing tag !

Answer (score 0):

You could allow some tags you want like this

```
let clean = DOMPurify.sanitize('<div>hello</div>',{ALLOWED_TAGS: ['b', 'q'], ALLOWED_ATTR: ['style']});
```

Comment: I used this but sill getting HTML tags in front side

Comment: I have attached image